# Как вернуться обратно в меню у бота aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

У меня есть бот, где при нажатии на кнопку "Сделать заказ", меняются кнопки на другие и бот должен войти в режим принятия текстового заказа, а потом дать возможность выйти обратно в главное меню. Как это можно сделать, если главное меню вызывается при команде start

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Привет, {message.from_user.full_name}", reply_markup=kb.inline_kb_full)
```

Обработка кнопок идёт здесь

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data and c.data.startswith('btn'))
async def process_callback_kb1btn1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    code = callback_query.data[-1]

    if code.isdigit():
        code = int(code)
    if code == 0:
        await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, "Заказывайте", reply_markup=kb.greet_kb1)
```

Comment: Машина состояний.

Comment: Госпаде боже, вы что с телебота пришли? Замените это `lambda c: c.data and c.data.startswith('btn')` на `text_startswith='btn'`

Comment: И в чем проблема тупо скопировать 1 строчку кода туда где вам нужно